# PIC32MX360 Coolterm

Tags: pic, microchip, pic32

I am trying to use Coolterm emulation program to send chars to test my program on a PIC32 starter kit. However, my PIC isn't showing as a usb device. I am using a USB - mini USB connection to the board. I've changed out different cables and nothing is working. [image]

I checked and the device is recognized by my mac. Can anyone please help me fix this?[image]

Comment: Have you compiled and installed code that would make it emulate a UART (USB CDC device)?

Comment: Yes, I configured UART through Code Harmony and successfully programmed the chip.